# Wordpress, мультиязычность,Jivosite

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть коды от `JIVOSITE` на 3 языках. Как при нажатии на один из языков сделать смену языка интерфейса?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите внимательно на документацию к этому модулю - [JIVOSITE](https://www.jivosite.ru/support/knowledge-base/article/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: да по документации понятно,там показано вставить каждый код  на шаблоны сайта для разных языков,я просто установил в footer шаблона js скрипт jivosite  сайте установлен плагин Polylang

Comment: я бы рад вам помочь больше, но к сожалению у меня нету сайта для проверки данного скрипта и написания более подробного ответа.

Comment: Polylang как переключает языки? Меняет урл? Домен? Или параметр урла? В футере надо сделать уловие `if ( 'ru' === pll_current_language() ) echo 'код для русского' `; Ну и по аналогии другие языки